# Colocar cor em uma imagem ou div com o valor de um campo no banco

Tags: php, css, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber se é possivel colocar o codigo da cor que está salva no banco de dados em uma imagem/div/icone. Funcionando assim, a pessoa preenche e o formulário e escolhe uma cor para ser a cor do tópico dela. 
é possivel? Tem algum site para recomendar?

Comment: Sim, totalmente possível. Basta passar a cor que foi escolhida pelo usuário para o banco de dados ou, no caso que você citou, gerar uma cor aleatória e fazer o mesmo procedimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode por exemplo criar uma tabela no banco de dados com o seguinte campo:

tabela usuario

id_usuario = 12345678 
nome_do_usuario = 'fer'; 
cor = "#FFF";

e no seu formulário ele fazer um cadastro nessa tabela, aonde cor será a cor escolhida pelo usuário na hora do cadastro.

Quando você for buscar os dados desse usuário no banco de dados, você busca a cor pelo id e atribui a uma variável por exemplo:

> Vale citar que a forma com a qual você irá buscar no banco de dados a variável "cor" depende de qual tecnologia você está utilizando (mysql, mysqli, PDO entre outras)

```
$query = select cor from usuario where id_usuario = 12345678
$resource= mysql_query($query);
$resultado = mysql_fetch_array($resource);
$cor = $resultado['cor'];
```

Para atribuir essa váriavel em uma div por exemplo o código é esse:

```
<div style="background-color: <?php echo $cor; ?>"><p>Minha div com a cor escolhida pelo usuário! </p></div>
```

Comment: É possível colocar cor em um ícone salvo no computador?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getColor(cor){
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style= 'color:' + cor;
  }
  document.getElementById("element-div").style.background = cor;
}
```

```css
.container-full {
  width: 90% !important;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

.element{
  color: green;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: green; 
    border: 2px solid green;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: blue; 
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button3 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: red; 
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.button4 {
    background-color: white;
    color: gray;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}

.button5 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-full text-center">
  <button class="button button1" onclick="getColor('Green')" >Green</button>
  <button class="button button2" onclick="getColor('Blue')" >Blue</button>
  <button class="button button3" onclick="getColor('Red')" >Red</button>
  <button class="button button4" onclick="getColor('Gray')" >Gray</button>
  <button class="button button5" onclick="getColor('Black')" >Black</button>
  <div id="element-div" style="background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; margin:10px"> Cor em Div   </div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; margin:10px">
    <p>Cor em Icon<p>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk element">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus element">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large element">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal element">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera element">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user element">
  </div>
</div>
```